# I want to make multiple list of coordinates from a single list of coordinates with can make a close loop

Tags: python, point-clouds

`input_list = [(2282.405, -89.9415, 266.1414), (2276.534, -89.9526, 266.9091), (2276.534, -83.9573, 266.9091), (2282.405, -83.9464, 266.1414), (2288.276, -77.9407, 265.3738), (2294.148, -77.9301, 264.6062), (2294.148, -83.9247, 264.6062), (2288.276, -83.9356, 265.3738), (2282.405, -71.9563, 266.1414), (2288.276, -71.9459, 265.3738), (2282.405, -77.9514, 266.1414), (2288.276, -89.9304, 265.3738), (2276.534, -77.962, 266.9091), (2294.148, -71.9355, 264.6062), (2276.534, -71.9667, 266.9091), (2294.148, -89.9193, 264.6062)]`

Requirement is to make 9 list which will contain coordinates of 4 points which forms a closed loop

[image]

I tried some ways by find the distances and then creating sets but the issue is with point which lies in the middle , there are 4 combinations comming up.

Requirement is to get exactly 9 list using python as shown in image , ( list will contains coordinates of 4 grids )
the sequence should be always anticlockwise

Answer (score 1):

Requiring to get "counterclockwise" answer, in a 3d assignment is tricky. A leaf has 2 sides, but I can imagine that the actual requirement is to always loop on the same order, and that if an edge is counted once "a to b", it will be counted "b to a" the next time.
Also your example look planar and "grid like". If this is really the assignment, I'd suggest using numpy eigenvector functions to reduce your coordinate system to 2d, then a transformation matrix to have your points aligned to (0,0),(0,1),etc.
To find this transformation matrix, take one point randomly, find the closest one on the x dimension, the closest one on the y dimension.
I'd say your assignment is more of a math assignment

Edit : I've given it a little more though. I really think that the simpliest answer is to make the most of the fact that :

1. You can simply enough find a corner point, and a corner square from your input,
2. A 3x3 grid of unitary squares can be transformed into your input, using the corner square as reference for the first unitary square. You just have to find the correct matrix for the matrix multiplication,
3. You can write by hand the loops for the unitary square, use a matrix addition to translate it as any square in the grid and project them using the previous matrix.

Comment: Thanks for you comment , yes 1st point is i reduced it to 2d coordinates , so i have only (x,y) But i need some help after that , (couter clockwise doesn't matter but all the sequence should be same)